# Determining if a function decreases exponentially

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Define a function:

$f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{e^{-kx}}{1-e^{-kx}}}$

where $k > 0$.

Does this function decrease exponentially?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant to ask just if it decreases exponentially.

Comment: Recall the definition of exponential function. Does $f$, considered as a function in $k$, satisfy this?

Comment: As $x\to +\infty$? Write it as $$f(x) = \frac{e^{-kx/2}}{\sqrt{1-e^{-kx}}}$$ and note that the denominator is basically constant.

Comment: Computing gives that $f'$ is not proportional (by a constant) to $f$, so $f$ is not exponential. As @DanielFischer hints, though, it is in a sense "asymptotically exponential".

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'm not sure I follow how you rewrote the function or why the denominator is basically a constant. Could you expand a bit? I see that if that all holds the function is just $f(x) = Me^{-\frac{k}{2} x}$, where $M$ is just the constant from the denominator. But, I'm not sure I understand the first part.

Comment: For large $x$, $e^{-kx}$ is very very small. So $1-e^{-kx}$ is very close to $1$ then. (If you want to make it more precise, expand $(1-u)^{-1/2}$ into a binomial series, or use a Taylor expansion of suitable order.) The rewriting just used $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}$ for positive $a,b$ and $\sqrt{e^y} = e^{y/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\sqrt{e^{-kx}} = e^{-kx/2}$ for the numerator. For the denominator, note that $1-e^{-kx} \leq 1,\,\forall x\geq 0$, and $1-e^{-kx} \geq \frac{1}{4}$ (say) when $x$ is sufficiently large. Hence, $\frac{1}{4} \leq 1-e^{-kx} \leq 1$ when $x$ is sufficiently large, and thus
$$e^{-kx/2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{e^{-kx}}{1-e^{-kx}}} \leq 2e^{-kx/2}$$
and your function decays "exactly exponentially."

Comment: If we assume that $x > 0$, do we need to assume that $x$ is "sufficiently large"? If $x$ is positive, then $0 < 1 - e^{-kx} < 1$. Isn't there always some constant $c$ that guarantees that $e^{-kx/2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{e^{-kx}}{1 - e^{-kx}}} \leq ce^{-kx/2}$? What do you mean by "exactly exponential"?

Comment: @Lord_Soth What do you mean be "exactly exponentially"? Why is it relevant that $e^{-kx/2} \leq f(x)$?